# How to find key words in paragraph of text?

Tags: javascript, database, caching, indexing, full-text-search

I'm trying to find a fast(milliseconds or seconds) solution for having an inputted block of text and a large list(11 million) of specific words/phrases to test against. So I would like to see what words/phrases are in the inputted paragraph?

We use Javascript and have SQL, MongoDB & DynamoDB as existing data stores that we can integrate this solution into.

I've done searching on this problem but can only find checking if words exist in text. not the other way around.

All ideas are welcome!

Comment: If you find that words/phrases exist in a block of text, doesn't that mean you've found words/phrases that are in the block of text? (I'm not sure why `I've done searching on this problem but can only find checking if words exist in text. not the other way around.` doesn't solve your problem)

Comment: For example: Say you have 2500 chars in your text input. Thats about 411 words that then need to be compared with the existing dictionary of 11million words. Thats 4521 million string comparisons. So how can we make this faster?

Comment: Hey! Any update on your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In cases like these you want to eliminate as much unnecessary data as possible. Assuming that order matters:

1. First things first, make sure you have a B tree index built on your phrases database clustered on the phrase. This will speed up range lookup times.
2. Let `n = 2` (or 1, if you're into that)
3. Split the text block into phrases of length `n` and perform a query for phrases in the dictionary that begin with any of the phrase pairs (`'My Phrase%'`). This won't perform 4521 million string comparisons thanks to the index.
4. Remember the phrases that are an exact match
5. Let `n = n + 1`
6. Repeat from step 3 using the reduced dictionary, until the reduced dictionary is empty

You can also make small optimizations here and there depending on the kind of matches you're looking for, such as, not matching across punctuation, only phrases of a certain word length, etc. In any case, I'd expect the time bottleneck here to be on disk access, rather than actual comparisons.

Also, I'm pretty sure I based this algorithm off of an existing one but I don't remember its name so bonus points to anyone who can name it. I think it had something to do with data warehousing/mining and calculating frequencies and patterns?